# How can I validate or format dates in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, date, data-validation

How would I format a date in a table such that the next row cannot have a date that precedes the current row?

For example, I have a table of 2 columns which have column headings "Date" and "Employee" and my first row (not the heading row) has the date as 20/10/2016. How do I ensure the next row cannot have a date that precedes 20/10/2016? (i.e. the next row's date must be the same or a date after 20/10/2016).

Thus if I have three rows of date values as 20/10/2016 and I start a new date 21/10/2016 then every succeeding row must be greater than or equal to 21/10/2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you tagged it as data validation, so why not use that?
Data tab -> Data validation ->
[image]

A2 being the first value in the list, and this being the data validation for A3.
Copying the cell to A4, will automatically change the validation to =A3.

Comment: Well in my case it will be 'greater than or equal to' for the data tab. Can this be implemented for a table i.e. if I have a start date value in a cell on another sheet and I carry out the data validation for the first row under column **date** in my 3 column table for instance and I append my table by either writing in the row cell below date column and hitting enter or by expanding it using the _invetered L_ at the end of each table does it automatically copy that validation to the next row?

Comment: It doesn't work just tried it. It must be the cell above. Unless you have a way to bypass this?

Comment: Well, it depends on exactly how you want it to work, but if you have the start date on anything but the 1st. row, the code will as your noticed still continue down from the start date. You can keep that from happening by changing from say "=Sheet2!A1" to an absolute reference "=Sheet2!$A$1". 
The problem with this however, is that now all rows will only be limited by the start date.
Another thing you could do, is to point the first row to the start date, and then use my example starting the second row. Downside would be if you delete the table rows, you'd have to set that validation again.

Comment: @MrMarho Ok, so I think I found a special solution to your problem. 
However, if you expand the table using the "inverted L" the data validation won't copy, then you'd need some kind of VBA.

Ok, so here is what I did: Say that your start date resides on sheet 2, cell H3. And your table with a text header is on sheet 1 column Q, starting with the header at Q3.
In Q4, add a **custom** data validation, **not date**.  and enter        

=AND(Sheet2!$H$3<=Q4;IF(CELL("format";Q3)="D1";Q3;Q4)<=Q4)

Change accordingly to your sheet. Make sure all date cells are formatted as "date".

Comment: If I understand your formula well this bit `IF(CELL("format";Q3)="D1";Q3;Q4)` says is cell format of Q3 is dd-mm-yyyy then output Q3 else Q4,

Comment: @MrMarho That's correct. As I want to check both the starting date and the row above me, the first row will get an error, since the header isn't a date. Therefore this checks if it's a date or not, and if it is not, it will return true (since Q4=Q4). So then it will only check against the starting date.

Comment: How does that then relate to the overall formula for what I'm trying to achieve because from what understand your formula says return true if cell H3 is sheet 2(i.e. value of start date) is less than or equal to value being entered in Q4 and if the output of `IF(CELL("format";Q3)="D1";Q3;Q4)` is less than or equal to Q4. If my understanding is wrong please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Ok so when it copies to the next row on the table will the validation code then update automatically to `=AND(Sheet2!$H$3<=Q5;IF(CELL("format";Q3)="D1";Q4;Q5)<=Q5)` ?

Comment: sorry the Q3 in `("format";Q3)` above is meant to be Q4. Is that what happens. Thanks and sorry for the mediocre question and the extended discussion

Comment: @MrMarho Yes exactly. So then it checks against the start date and the row above as it should. The only reason to check both is so that it will work on the first row as well as the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Eg to construct a SQL statement:

```
="insert into qualification (created_date) VALUES ('" & TEXT(Q3,"dd/mm/yyyy") & "')"
```